# How to resize existing product images backend?

Tags: programmatically, third-party-module, magento-1.9.3.4

I am Using third-party extension to Import product images https://www.magebees.com/magento-import-export-simple-products-configurable-products-bundle-products-group-products-downloadable-products.html

It is working But Problem is there is no limit of image size. Any Dimension image uploads(import) successfully.
I have all images around size 22mb and width and height (1132832x21212).

Store frontend gives fetal error memory allocation limit.
Please help me Is there any function of import media images before I change Images dimension and size.
Or what to do with existing products backend import successful Images (Can Resize it).

Thanks;

Comment: how large is your `media/catalog/` folder? I would consider zipping it, downloading to your computer, running through local software to modify images, then replace current contents with newly downsized images.

Comment: Around 45gb folder size.and products around 35000. Looking for better solution.thanks

Comment: I guess something like this (resizing images from CLI using imagemagick) should be helpful.. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1164/how-to-easily-resize-images-via-command-line

Comment: I agree with Cristoph. You'll need something server-side to handle that many photos at that large of disk usage. Where did you download the images from that have such high resolution and file size?

Comment: @StevenJ manufacturer give me studio images so basically It's higher resolution and size. I am looking for Magento resize function. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Try this extension. It's free and you can manage a lot of settings based on your preferences

https://www.apptrian.com/image-optimizer-for-magento